# Inverse of an antecedent

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, anaphora

An antecedent refers to an earlier noun to derive its meaning, for example,

> Taylor likes his pizza hot.

Here, *his* derives its meaning from *Taylor*.

What is the anaphora or inverse of the antecedent? (I am looking for a grammatical category paired with antecedent). It might be a *pronoun* or a *proform*, these don't seem to be the inverse of antecedent.

It is not a *postcedent*, in which the pronoun precedes what it refers to.

Comment: Are you talking about what the word for the pronoun (which has an antecedent) is? Why wouldn't it just be "proform," as you already note in your question?

Comment: Actually, the antecedent *is* the earlier term from which the *proform* derives its meaning.Tayler is the antecedent and his is the proform. I don't understand what you mean with 'inverse' though in this case

Comment: It might be proform, Katherine. But *antecedent* doesn't seem well paired with *proform*. Pronouns are a basic part of grammar. We learn how to use them in second grade. To discuss antecedents, though, we have to have something more advanced than grammar school. I didn't learn about anaphora until college. That's why these two don't seem like inverses to me. I don't think nephew : uncle :: antecedent : proform. But I'm not ruling it out, either.

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for [pro-form](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/pro-form), which Oxford Living Dictionaries defines as

> (linguistics) A word or lexical unit that is dependent for its meaning on reference to some other part of the context or sentence in which it occurs, for example, a pronoun replacing a noun or noun phrase, or a verb replacing a clause, such as **do** in "she likes chocolate and so **do** I."

(emphasis and quotation marks above added for clarity.)

Pro-forms can substitute not only for nouns (where the pro-form is a pronoun), but for various parts of speech--even verbs, in a sentence like

> She ordered the pasta, and so **did** I.

in which **did** takes the place of "ordered," or adverbs, as in

> I spoke softly, which was **how** she spoke too.

Comment: Let's consider a subject - linking verb - complement, like "Taylor felt sick." (Possibly from too much pizza.) Here, the grammatical term *complement* tells you that it stands in relation to something else (namely Taylor). If I used a different grammatical term for "sick" such as "adjective", it would still be correct. However, it wouldn't capture its role in the sentence or its relation to the subject. I might be mistaken, but "pronoun" tells me that the word stands for a noun; it says nothing about its relation to the antecedent. I hoping there's a word that mea

Comment: ...that means "the proform corresponding to the antecedent."

Comment: I don't entirely understand the question in your comment. Pro-form can be various parts of speech. Each pro-form has to reference something. So what I'm not understanding is your question about "a word that means the pro-form corresponding to the antecedent." That's what the pro-form is.

Comment: Sorry, Katherine, my murky understanding is contributing the problem. Let me try again. In the Subj/V/Comp, the complement is often an adjective. In the Antecedent/xyz, the xyz is often a pronoun. "Pronoun" and "adjective" are in a similar grammatical category (basics that we learn in grammar school). "Complement" and xyz are in a similar grammatical category (terms that we learn later that must refer to something else). "Adjective" and "pronoun" are in the same grammatical categories. But "complement" and "proform" seem to be grammatically different, to my ear. I'll take another look at OLD.

Answer (score 2):

If two words or phrases in a sentence have the same referent, one being a pronoun and the other being a lexical word or phrase, this is a case of **anaphora**. We can call the pronoun an **anaphor**, and the lexical term the pronoun's antecedent. This terminology is especially useful when you are discussing how to analyze a sentence in a foreign language. So what if the pronoun comes after the lexical term (in which case it's called a **cataphor** rather than an anaphor)? Is the lexical term still called an antecedent?

It looks like semanticists and linguists still call it an antecedent. See for example the following from the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy entry for [anaphora](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/anaphora/):

> The antecedent also does not always have to precede the anaphoric
>   expression; when it doesn’t, these are called cases of cataphora or
>   backwards anaphora:

Sure, **antecedent** is not being used true to its etymology, but we still know exactly what you're talking about.

Comment: So the semanticists and linguists would say that both "Taylor" AND "his" are antecedents? Or only if the sentence was "His pizza was hot, just the way Taylor liked it."

Comment: @rajah9, no, a pronoun cannot be an antecedent. "Taylor" is the antecedent regardless of whether it appears before or after "his".

Comment: OK, so the "his" refers to Taylor in both "Taylor likes his pizza hot" and "His pizza was hot, just the way Taylor liked it". Would you call "his" the *anaphora* regardless of post-positioning or pre-positioning?